# How to install a specific version of antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, yarnpkg

In the latest antd v4 to v5 migration, it is [mentioned](https://ant.design/docs/react/migration-v5) to first migrate to the most recent stable version of v4 which is `v4.24.3`, and then migrate to v5.

I tried doing `yarn add antd`

But this gives the latest stable version (`5.0.1`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mention the version at the end

Using `yarn`

```
yarn add antd@4.24.3
```

Using `npm`

```
npm i antd@4.24.3
```